# Can someone look at my gulp file and tell me why it might be so slow to run?

Tags: node.js, web, gulp

It takes far too long usually. On my laptop it literally never finishes. The PHP watch is supposed to be checking for PHP saves in the root and in any sub-directories. I'm not sure if I have the glob correct there, and maybe that's what's causing the problem?

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var sass = require('gulp-sass');
    var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
    var mmq = require('gulp-merge-media-queries');
    var phpConnect = require('gulp-connect-php');
    var autoPrefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');


    gulp.task('sass', function() {
      return gulp.src('assets/css/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass()) // Converts Sass to CSS with gulp-sass
        .pipe(autoPrefixer({
                browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
                cascade: false
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'));
    });

    gulp.task('connect-sync', function() {
      phpConnect.server({}, function (){
        browserSync({
          proxy: '127.0.0.1:8000'
        });
      });
    });

    gulp.task('mmq', ['sass'], function () {
      gulp.src('assets/css/styles.css')
        .pipe(mmq({
          log: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
          stream: true
    }));
    });

    gulp.task('watch', ['connect-sync', 'sass', 'mmq'], function(){
     gulp.watch('assets/css/**/*.scss', ['sass', 'mmq']);
     gulp.watch('/**/*.php', browserSync.reload);
     gulp.watch('assets/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
      // Other watchers
    });
```

Comment: Did you check if gulp file and assets are in the same directory? Also, you can check for assets directory permissions.

Comment: Should they be in the same directory? My gulpfile is in the root.

Comment: You can start by trying these tasks individually to narrow down which one is causing the slow down.

Comment: you want to keep it in the root. Can you check what's the root path your gulp installation resolve to? You can do it by var path = process.cwd(); Post your results here.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that gulp checks your node_modules folder? This is known to slow gulptasks down. 
Try running each gulp statement from the console, i.e. First try gulp sass, then gulp connect. 
Can you post the output from your console plz?

Comment: @user3669771 is this still active?